# Font of titles of "The Outer Limits" series

Tags: font-identification, tv-series

Which font is used in "The Outer Limits" (1995 TV series)? I mean this for the titles, actors and so on, as in included picture.

As one can see from my profile, I know mainly TeX fonts, but this one is extremely beautiful for me.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font is [Carolus Roman](http://www.dafont.com/font.php?file=carolus_roman&text=Sofia+Shinas), with a bevel added. It appears to be available free.

[image: Carolus Roman]

Comment: The free version that I have found looks a bit different, but it is the shape that I have been searching. :-)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like [Optima Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/optima/) with forced small caps and a bevel effect.